# Do nodes accept non-standard output scripts in a mined block?

Tags: consensus, mempool, block-validity, non-standard-transaction

As I understand, transactions with non-standard output scripts won't be propagated through the network. I'm wondering if I were to mine a block with weird transactions whether it would be accepted by nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a valid block containing non-standard transactions would be accepted by nodes. The rules for mempool acceptance, called “mempool policy” are much stricter than the consensus rules that apply to validating a block.